# Set the correct spender when calling gasless transferFrom from another contract with GSN

Tags: erc-20, gas, msg.sender, erc2771

Actually I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement gasless call to `transferFrom` of a ERC-20 token.

I'm not very familiar with GSN so maybe it could be a best way to achieve this.

I wrote a smart contract with `ERC2771Recipient` and I call the `transferFrom` function from `myToken` ERC-20 contract.

This is the contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@opengsn/contracts/src/ERC2771Recipient.sol";
import "./token.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC2771Recipient {
    event TransferredFromTokenGSN(address from, address to, uint256 amount);

    token public myToken;

    constructor(address _trustedForwarder, address _Token) {
        _setTrustedForwarder(_trustedForwarder);
        myToken = Token(_Token);
    }

    function transferFromTokenGSN(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external {
        myToken.transferFrom(from, to, amount);

        emit TransferredFromTokenGSN(from, to, amount);
    }
}
```

The problem obviously is that the `msg.sender` and so the `spender` of the `transferFrom` function is the `myContract` address instead of the original address that submit the transaction.

Any suggestions to set the original wallet address as `spender` of the `transferFrom` function?